# Unresolved reference: viewModels()

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

I just started an Android App and I want to use ViewModel. I looked into documentation and I put all the dependencies from [Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle) but when i try to instantiate a view model like this view`MyViewModel by viewModels()` i get this error 'Unresolved reference: viewModels()'.

These are the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
    def arch_version = "2.1.0"

    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version"

    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$arch_version"

}
```

Comment: I think this question deserves to be re-opened. Although the subject is similar to the other one but the actual problem faced by him is different.

Answer (score 2):

Include this in your dependency,

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
```

then, add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` in build.gradle

then add,

```
kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
```

Replace other `annotationProcessor` with `kapt`

See if it works or not, if not, then go to

> file -> invalidate cache and restart

Comment: Still doesn't work. I added the dependencies, maybe it helps

Comment: try to rebuild the project